# What is the proper indentation of return statement in python?

Tags: python-3.x, return, indentation

```
>>> from pytdx.hq import TdxHq_API
>>>
>>> market_data={}
>>> def get_latest_prices(stock_codes):
...     api = TdxHq_API()
...     with api.connect('119.147.212.81', 7709):
...         market_data = api.get_security_quotes(stock_codes)
...     api.disconnect()
...
>>> latest_prices = {}
>>> for data in market_data:
...         stock_code = data['code']
...         latest_price = data['price']
...         latest_prices[stock_code] = latest_price
...     return latest_prices
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    return latest_prices
                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
>>>
```

After changing it to

```
from pytdx.hq import TdxHq_API


def get_latest_prices(stock_codes):
    api = TdxHq_API()
    with api.connect('119.147.212.81', 7709):
        market_data = api.get_security_quotes(stock_codes)
    api.disconnect()
    latest_prices = {}
    for data in market_data:
        stock_code = data['code']
        latest_price = data['price']
        latest_prices[stock_code] = latest_price
return latest_prices
```

I get

```
 Cell In[36], line 14
    return latest_prices
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: There is no blank line in the middle of a function definition

Comment: Yes there is, after `api.disconnect()`.

Comment: Okay, *now* you broke the `return` statement's indentation. It was fine originally, but you changed it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a totally blank line in the middle of a function definition (or other block statement) in interactive mode. It looks to me like you broke your function definition by including a blank line, then broke the indentation of the next two lines after the blank line trying to fix that.

The `return` statement's indentation is fine. You need to remove the blank line and indent the two lines after it.